# regex finding only 1 apostrophe (not 2 or more) in one shot

Tags: regex, apostrophe

Find one apostrophe in the expression:
 "**[Field1] IN ('121',''122'','123',''12F'','131')**" 
= only results with one apostrophe (not 2 or more apostrophes)
wrong expression: `['](?![']{1,})`

Result should be:
' *= position 14*
' *= position 18*
' *= position 28*
' *= position 32*
' *= position 42*
' *= position 46*
Thank you for help.

Comment: Maybe use two lookarounds [`(?<!')'(?!')`](https://regex101.com/r/dGNER3/2)

Comment: Hello , thank you for the solution. Unfortunately it doesn't work in VBscript.regex library: Result: "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Right, you haven't mentioned this in your actual question. Different flavors have different abilities. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/9758194) link for information. You can see that lookbehind is not supported indeed.